# How can I partly compile a python file?

Tags: linux, compilation, pyinstaller, python-3.7, source-code-protection

How can I compile a python file exclude a certain module?

Let's see a example:

there is `def b()` in `b.py` called in `main.py`, how can I just compile `main.py`, because I need to modify `def b()` in `b.py` afterward. Or can I compile them separately?

I am using `pyinstaller` now, but I can change to other compile tools if it can implement this.

Thanks

Comment: Pyinstaller won't compile your code it just bundles it with a python interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea to do this: pyinstaller is meant for packaging and distribution, not for development. Packaged file aren't meant to be changed. If part of the program is modified, you should release a new version of the whole package. If you would like to do runtime configuration, then you should use a configuration file, rather than changing the program.

However, if you insist on doing it, you could use the `--exclude-module` flag. Run

```
pyinstaller --exclude-module b main.py
```

so that `b` is not bundled with main. If you try to run the bundled package now, a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'` would show. Copy `b.py` to the directory (`dist/main`), run `main`, and everything would work again. Now you could change `b.py`, and the difference would show during the execution.

Answer (score 0):

For single .exe file output for .py file :

```
python -m pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller -D -F --debug [.py file path]
```